# package.json dependency not updating ^0.0.130 to ^0.0.145 when 1.0.145 is the latest

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, package.json

In the **package.json** of my reactjs webpack project I specified the version number of a dependency that I wanted to download through a **npm install** as **^0.0.130** where the latest version of that dependency is **0.0.145**.

But when I hit the **npm install** its  downloading **0.0.130**, not the latest version.

But when I specified the version number as **^0.0.145** its downloading the latest version of **0.0.145**.

I cannot figure out why its not downloading the latest version though i used caret sign (**^**) with the eailer number.

Can anyone help me to figure out why this is not happening in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

`^0.0.145` matches the most recent `^0.x.x` version

To upgrade to latest version for the 1.0.0 major release you will need to use something like`^1.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, That can be happen.

After a component is publishing using **npm publish** command the latest version is usually the highest version number. But if a component is published using **npm publish --tag latest** that version is marked as the latest one. So though you published new versions after that the latest version will be the eariler version.

In above scenario they published **0.0.130** as the latest version using  **npm publish --tag latest**. So though they published new versions after that, **^0.0.130** is the latest one.

```
0.0.145
.......
.......
.......
0.0.131
0.0.130 --------latest
0.0.129
0.0.128
0.0.127
```